# Select an element after another element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I select the element after an element in JavaScript?

As example I need to add a class to the element after an element when hovering over it

Comment: Do you mind using jquery?

Comment: Give an example of what you wanted to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next element is stored in `nextElementSibling` property of the specific element on javascript.

Comment: [this is what happens when you use nextSibling](https://jsfiddle.net/mtgvjLqa/)

Comment: Oh, I see what you want.
In your case use `nextElementSibling`

Comment: I see. Today I learned. thank you

Answer (score 2):

All you need is **CSS** and the `+` [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```
#target:hover + * {/*styles here*/}
```

By using **JavaScript** you can use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

Comment: I can't imagine this has ever been asked before...